# How to share image along with some text in android twitter?

Tags: android, media, twitter4j

I want to add an image along with some text from my android native app. I saw several links that propose intent sharing.but i don't want that. How i can obtain this using twitter4j.  I found a twitpic jar that allows image sharing. It is working ,but it share that in facebook also and it shows twitpic in tweet.Can we avoid that facebook sharing? or is it possible to share image using twitter4j_media_support jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/tutorial-on-uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitter4j/) tutorial.

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key));

configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));

configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(LoginActivity.getAccessToken((context)));

configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(LoginActivity.getAccessTokenSecret(context));

Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);

status.setMedia(file); // set the image to be uploaded here.

twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
private void sendShareTwit() { 
    try { 
        Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        String filename = "<file path>/twitter_image.jpg";
        File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, twitter_share_text);
        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> lract = pm.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean resolved = false;
        for (ResolveInfo ri : lract) {
            if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains("twitter")) {
                tweetIntent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
                        ri.activityInfo.name);
                resolved = true;
                break; 
            } 
        } 

        startActivity(resolved ?
                tweetIntent :
                Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Choose one"));
    } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.rintln( "You don't seem to have twitter installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT));
    } 
}
```